# What is the chance of a successful event after N failed trials?

Tags: probability, statistics

Forgive me if this has been answered, but I couldn't quite find what I'm looking for. Maybe I'm not used to the mathematical terms.

Say there is an event with a chance of 1 in 20 of being successful. This chance doesn't change in each trial.

If there were N trials (let's say 2 for a concrete example), then what is the chance of the next trial (N+1) being successful?

Trial 1: Fail
Trial 2: Fail
Trial 3: ?

Comment: You say that the trials are independent (i.e. "[t]his chance doesn't change in each trial"), which means that the probability of the $(N+1)$-st trial being successful is the same as any other trial.  It doesn't matter what has happened before.  Or are you maybe interested in the probability of the first success being on the $(N+1)$-st trial?  That is a different question...

Comment: Are the trials independent? Btw, events happen with a certain probability. It is not so that they are succesful (or not). That is what you can say about "experiments".

Comment: Yes, the trials are independent. I know the real chance is always 1/20, but how unlucky can someone be? Surely, there must be some sort of approximation to success?

Comment: Then the probability is $\frac1{20}$ for *every* trial, no matter what the results are by any other trial.

Comment: @XanderHenderson A not changing chance for each trial does not imply independence. E.g. you could have $X_1=X_2=X_3=\cdots$ where $X_i$ denotes the number of successes at trial $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arthur said, the probability 'resets' after each individual trial (that might almost be considered the definition of independent trials). So although the probability of waiting for large N before success decreases as N grows, the probability of success in the next M trials after N failures is completely independent of N. This can be illustrated using your own simulated data. The black line is the probability of success after N trials/attempts. The red, blue, and green lines are the probability of success of the remaining trials in the case that the first 50, 100, 150 (respectively) failed. Note that the lines are superimposed on top of the black line.

This demonstrates that even after (for example) 150 failures, the likelihood of success in the following trials is no different than it is when starting 'fresh' with no failures. In other words, no matter how lucky or unlucky or improbable you consider the past events - the probability of success in the future remains unchanged.

So if, for example, you had the extraordinary luck to toss heads 100 times in a row when tossing a **provably fair** coin (chance = 1 in 2^100), the likely wait before tossing tails *from that point in time onward* is no different to what it would be if you had just tossed 100 tails in a row, or a combination of 47 Heads and 53 tails or whatever...

And thus, to answer your original question after two failed trials (your concrete example), the probability of success in the next trial is still 1/20.

[image]

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because that chart or something similar is what I was looking for anyway, and no one told me how to calculate it, but at least you showed it. I'm implementing a luck system and I need to know how lucky or unlucky a certain event is for person X so that I can tweak the odds dynamically to prevent frustrated players and keep the economy balanced.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how your trials are set up. Specifically whether they're independent or not. Look at two cases:

1. Each trial is throwing a 20-sided die, and success is if you get a 20. In this case trial 3 will still have a 1 in 20 probability of success, no matter what happened in trial 1 or 2. This goes against the intuition that many people have ("surely after 30 fails I must be getting close"), but that is entirely false. The die *does not remember* and *does not keep track*.
2. You have picked out 19 black playing cards and one red, and shuffled teen together. Each trial is picking the top card, looking at it, and then throwing it away. Success is if you draw the red card. In this case, failure on the first 2 trials means you have a 1 in 18 chance of success on the third trial.

(There is a 1.5 where you picked out 19000000 black cards and 1000000 cards.) Note that in both cases, the probability of success on any specific trial is 1 in 20. But in the second case knowledge of the result of other trials changes the probability.

Comment: It's case 1 and I understand that but isn't there a way to tell how close you are? If you toss a coin the outcome is always heads or tails, but after a million tries, surely at least heads came out once?

Comment: @aLfa Nope. No such thing. The probability resets completely for each trial. As I said above, many find this counterintuitive and firmly believe that there is _some_ mechanism, somewhere, making it more like situation number 2 above. But that's not true.

Comment: @aLfa As Arthur says. By a millon tries you can at most become somewhat suspicious concerning the $\frac1{20}$.

Comment: So, what's being suspicious? Is it calculable? How *likely* it is that in 1m tries, the outcome is always the same? Just found out about this "Bernoulli trial" thing and seems to be what I want. Will read more about it o:

Comment: @drhab so I just made a quick script to simulate my use case and these are the results with 100m attempts: https://gist.github.com/alfaproject/89e378cc5b5e4414fced9a35e8890586

Each attempt rolls the 20 sided dice until it hits success. Based on that, wouldn't you say it's possible to extrapolate a probability out of a specific number of tries to get a success?

Comment: @aLfa If you take those trials, extract the ones with failure at attempts 1 and 2, and recalculate the percentages, you will see the (approximately) exact same numbers appear, starting with $5\%$ success at trial 3 and $4.75\%$ at trial 4.

Comment: I don't think I'm expressing myself well. ): I know that the probability of any single try doesn't change (it will always be 5%), but statistically speaking, a successful try will happen sooner or later: 5% in 1 try, 9.75% in 2 tries, until it gets to a point that it's 99.(9)%.
I just want to know how close I am from that ceiling, given that N tries have occurred. If 2 tries have failed already, I know that in 9.75% of the cases it would have already been successful, so I still need to try for the other 'infinite' cases. If I'm in 3rd try then I'm 9.75% 'closer' to have a successful one.

Comment: @aLfa You're not _guaranteed_ that it will happen sooner or later. But you're right, most likely it will. However, if you have failed a number of times already, or if you haven't had any trials yet doesn't matter. It's not more likely to happen soon just because you have already failed 50 times, or 100, or a million.

Comment: I made that simulation to prove that it matters. I just don't know how to translate it into a formula. Maybe I can't put my thoughts into words.
My goal is to do something like: "Given a probability P of event E being successful and that F fails have happened, you are X% 'closer' to a successful try."
It looks like this gives the results of my simulation, so I guess I'm one step closer: https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573193

Comment: @aLfa In short: if there is a probability on success of e.g. $0.05$ then the probability that a success has been achieved at at least one of the first $1000$ trials is quite large. But the probability on a success on the next $10$  trials $1001,\dots,1010$ does **not** depend on the question whether there was indeed a success on the first $1000$ trials or not. If you come to another conclusion on base of a simulation then you are probably misinterpreting the results of the simulation.

Comment: @aLfa I looked at the (first few) numbers of the simulation, and what I saw was that it didn't matter. Among the trials which failed on the first two attempts, $5.0068\%$ succeeded on the first trial after those two fails (compare to $5.0054\%$ succeses on the original first attempt, using more digits), $4.754\%$ succeeded on the second (compare to $4.745\%$), and $4.516\%$ succeded on the third (against $4.518$ in total on original third attempt). I know it's not _exactly_ the same percentages, and I can't say that it directly confirms my view, but it definitely isn't enough to confirm yours.

Comment: I think I've worded this incorrectly, so I apologise for that. I know that the odds of every single try don't change. I also know that given enough tries (up to infinite), eventually, one will be a success, and it will be successful closer to 0 rather than infinite as the chart by the accepted answer portrays. In theory, if you flip a coin until the end of the world, you could always get heads. In practice, the world will throw a tail at you eventually. I'm pretty sure someone studied this stuff, I just don't know what to call it.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, you write:

> Surely, there must be some sort of approximation to success?

One of the main difficulties students face when first encountering probability is that, in fact, there is no such approximation, and your initial intuitions can consequently be deceiving. [Historically, this has made a lot of people broke,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) so I'm glad you asked about it here :)

Comment: I'm not doing this for gambling. I'm making a game and trying to balance the economy. (: